# Difference between train(), run() and fit() functions in Spark

Tags: machine-learning

There are several options of using logistic regression with Apache Spark (Version 1.5.2) in Java:

spark.ml:

```
1) LogisticRegression lr = new LogisticRegression();
a) lr.train(dataFrame);
b) lr.fit(dataFrame);
```

spark.mllib:

```
2) LogisticRegressionWithSGD lr = new LogisticRegressionWithSGD();
a) lr.train(rdd);
b) lr.run(rdd);

3) LogisticRegressionWithLBFGS lr = new LogisticRegressionWithLBFGS();
a) lr.train(rdd);
b) lr.run(rdd);
```

I was wondering what is the difference between a) and b), except the **GeneralizedLinearAlgorithm** output from **run()** function instead of **LogisticRegressionModel** from the other? I couldn't find any hint in the Java or Scala documentation. Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Spark does contain two libraries that can be used for machine learning: ML and MLLib. Could you specify which version of Spark you're using please?

**MLLib.** It was the first machine learning library of Spark. It actually has a very shallow structure and uses `RDD` to be run on. This is kind of anarchical in MLLib and so you have to look at the code to know which one to use. I'm not sure which language or version you're using, but for Spark 1.6.0 on scala, there's a singleton:

```
object LogisticRegressionWithSGD {
   def train(input: RDD[LabeledPoint], ...) = new LogisticRegressionWithSGD(...).run(input,...)
}
```

which means that train is to be called as a static method on the object `LogisticRegressionWithSGD`, but if you have an instance of `LogisticRegressionWithSGD` there's only a `run` method:

```
LogisticRegressionWithSGD.train(rdd, parameters) 
// OR
val lr = new LogisticRegressionWithSGD() 
lr.run(rdd)
```

anyway, if you have another version, you sould definitly perfer the super version, i.e. `run`.

**ML.** It's the newest library that's based on the use of `DataFrame`, which is basically an `RDD[Row]` (a `Row` is just a sequence of untyped objects) with a schema (ie an object that contains information about the colum names, types, metadata...). I definitly advise you to use this as it enables optimizations! In this case, you should use the `fit` method which is the method that all the estimators need to implement.

*Explanation:* The ML library uses the notion of `Pipeline` (kind of the same as in sci-kit learn). A pipeline instance is basically an array of stages (of type `PipelineStage`), each one of them being either an `Estimator` or a `Transformer` (there are some other types, e.g. `Evaluator` but I won't get into them here as they are being rare). A `Transformer` is simply an algorithm that transforms your data, so its main method is `transform(DataFrame)` and it outputs another `DataFrame`. An `Estimator` is a an algorithm that produces a `Model` (a subtype of `Transformer`). It's basically any block that needs to fit on data, so it has a function `fit(DataFrame)` that outputs a `Transformer`. For instance if you want to multiply all your data by $2$, you only need a transformer that implements a transform method that takes your input and multiply it by $2$. If you need to compute the mean and substract it, you need an estimator that fits on the data to compute the mean and outputs a transformer the substracts the mean learned. So any time you use ML, use the `fit` and `transform` methods. It allows you to do something like:

```
val trainingSet = // training DataFrame
val testSet = // test DataFrame
val lr = new LogisticRegession().setInputCol(...).setOutputCol(...) // + setParams()
val stage = // another stage, i.e. something that implements PipelineStage
val stages = Array(lr, stage)
val pipeline: Pipeline = new Pipeline().setStages(stages)
val model: PipelineModel = pipeline.fit(trainingSet)
val result: DataFrame = model.transform(testSet)
```

Now if you really want to know why `train` exists, it's a function inherited by `Predictor` which itself extends `Estimator`. Indeed there are a tones of possible `Estimators` - you could compute the mean, IDF,... When you implement a predictor such as the logistic regression you have an abstract class `Predictor` that extends `Estimator` and allows you some shortcuts (e.g. it has a label column, feature column and prediction column). In particular the piece of code already overrides `fit` to change the schema of your dataframe accordingly to those label/features/prediction and you simply need to implement your own train:

```
override def fit(dataset: DataFrame): M = {
   // This handles a few items such as schema validation.
   // Developers only need to implement train().
   transformSchema(dataset.schema, logging = true)
   copyValues(train(dataset).setParent(this))
}
protected def train(dataset: DataFrame): M
```

as you see the `train` method should be protected/private so not used by an external user.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying the static / non-static access of logistic regression in **MLlib**, you are definitely right. But I still can't see the difference of using fit() over train() in **Spark ML**, since both options return the same **LogisticRegressionModel**.

Comment: I tried to give you an insight of how it works in the ML library, tell me if something's not clear or if you're not cumfortable with scala code.

Comment: From your detailed explanation I guess the main point of using train() over fit() is a different way of handling the data.

Comment: Not exactly, calling fit(dataframe) will take care of all the processing common to predictors, e.g. check that the column of labels and features exist and create a prediction column in the schema. train() does the core work but is private/protected and sould'nt be used externally (as you don't know if you use it that your label column does exist e.g.). Moreover, the main use of ML is to wrap sequences of algorithms into Pipelines, in this case it's the fit() function that's called.